Inherited an old fridge. How to fix cooling before getting a new unit?
I inherited an old fridge and noticed that it doesn't cool very well, most likely because the seal is very old and broken. How can I DIY this to be a bit better before I get a new unit?



If this was mine, I’d try cheap temporary weatherstripping foam before spending on an oem solution. Obviously, the seal is bad, but there might be other, more expensive problems with the fridge.

Note that if the fridge is more than 10 years old, buying a new fridge may pay for itself in energy savings. There are often rebates to encourage upgrading old appliances which reduce the cost of doing so. By all means apply a cheap temporary fix to hold you while you look for a replacement, but...

Is the fridge working often/almost constantly?  If not, most likely other problems than a bad seal.

@keshlam   From what I have read about new fridges, you are lucky if they last long enough for the savings to kick in.

@crip659: No problems with mine so far. I have my quibbles with Consumers Union, but their frequency of repair surveys are a useful thing to consult.

I am assuming ny new you mean new fridge.
First contact the manufacturer or look on their website to ensure a replacement is available.
Then remove the old one and see how its tucked in.
Then you should be able to put the new one in.

No need to even contact the manufacturer.  There are several appliance parts sites out there where you can cross reference the make and model and find parts.  Once you have a part number, you may even be able to find it cheaper elsewhere, e.g. used on eBay (though IDK how much life a used door seal may have, but still good advice for other parts).
